# Error: Too few positional arguments: 4 required, 0 given

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to create a clock app, I created a constructor for the parameters for the world clock here;

```
class WorldClock {

  String flag;
  String location;
  String time;
  String url;

  WorldClock(this.flag, this.location, this.url,this.time);
```

I called this class in the Parent class using three of these constructor here;

```
void setupWorldtime() async{

    WorldClock instance = WorldClock(location:'Berlin',url:'Europe/Berlin');(source of the error msg)
    await instance.getime();
    print(instance.time);
    setState(() {
      time = instance.time;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call named constructor and force the attributes to be called, it is necessary to wrap it with curly brackets and add required keyword at the beginning of each attribute.

```
class WorldClock {

  String flag;
  String location;
  String time;
  String url;

  WorldClock({required this.flag,required this.location,required this.url,required this.time});
}
```

Comment: I still got an error message though a different one

Comment: Like what? I assume this one is fixed

Comment: yes, your idea helped a lot thanks. the new dependency came with complications, so i went with my instructors dependency .